# Extarcting string stored in coulmn as series values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, string, csv, select

I have a table which has column storing values as comma separated values.

I need to extarct specific value like '2' and 10 in ever row of the column.I tried substr but cannot arrive into result.How can we achieve this in msql

My table looks like as attached as screenshot

[image]

Comment: Please show us the results that you expect.

Comment: I expect value 2 and 10 in each row .That was given as expected result

Comment: *That was given as expected result* I see example source data and do NOT see desired result. Especially for the first row, where the value `2` is present twice.

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store multiple values in strings!  Don't store numbers as strings!  Declare foreign key relationships!

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `find_in_set()`:

```
select
    channel,
    find_in_set('2',  channel) > 0 has_2,
    find_in_set('10', channel) > 0 has_10
from mytable
```

This adds two columns to the table with a boolean value that indicates whether values `2` and `10` are available in `channel`.

Comment: For MySQL `> 0` seems to be excess. What's the difference, some non-zero value or strictly one?

Comment: @Akina: yes, my idea was to return a booean value (so either `0` or `1`), hence the `> 0`... We could leave it apart as well.